# Existe um código Css genérico para tranformar meu site em "mobile Friendly"?

Tags: html, css, mobile, blog

Gostaria de transformar meu site em mobile Friendly.

Sei que dá para fazer por css pois não pretendo mudar o template da página web.

Comment: não existe um css genérico que faça milagre, você precisaria modificar o css para deixa-lo amigável, porém precisará mudar algumas tags de html tb.

Answer (score 0):

Nada mágico, você pode importar as libs do [Boostrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com), e aplicar tamanho e proporções de acordo com o tamanho do device. Basta seguir as orientações do [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) e criar seus layout adaptivos.

Comment: Já baixei as libs Thiago. O meu blog ainda está relacionado ao blogger. Tenho que mudar o servidor para poder fazer o upload destas libs né? sites [www.pegadadelixo.com.br]   [pedroaguiar.me]